# Syntax highlighting in Sublime 3 - highlight until equal number of begin/end characters

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to get the correct syntax highlighting for a nested expression. The pattern is that all text between **`** (grave accent) and **'** should be highlighted until there are an equal number of **`** and **'** characters. For example, all of these expressions should be highlighted in their entirety (what may look like double quotes are actually two single apostrophes):

```
`variable'  
`variable_`1''  
`variable_`1'_`1''
```

The problem is that I cannot get the last expression to fully highlight. The second underscore is not highlighted because the first **'** is returning a positive match. (The second underscore could be any character, so there needs to be a general solution.) Right now I have:

```
<dict>
  <key>begin</key>
  <string>`(?!")</string>
  <key>end</key>
  <string>(?&lt;!")''|'</string>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>string.quoted.single.stata</string>
</dict>
```

The expressions within parentheses are lookaheads and lookbehinds that need to remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a TextMate grammar for a different syntax with variables that can be nested like this `${var1${var2}}`. It's possible with a regex, but you can only handle the level of nesting that you specify because regex is not recursive.

I had more success with the `$self` sub-pattern for arbitrarily nested variables.

```
<!-- Variables with nested variables -->
<key>VariableNested</key>
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>\$\{</string>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>\}</string>

    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <!-- recursive match on $self -->
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>$self</string>
        </dict>
        <!-- the variable name inside the brackets -->
        <dict>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>[^}]</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>variable</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I think you could modify this for your purpose.

```
<!-- Variables with nested variables -->
<key>VariableNested</key>
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>`</string>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>'</string>

    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <!-- recursive match on $self -->
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>$self</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Here's a link to the [TextMate manual](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) where they briefly (!) explain a few things.

Comment: Thanks so much!, this is really helpful and solves the issue, was not aware of the $self sub-pattern. For anyone else with this issue, this really allows you to replicate Stata syntax highlighting on macros.

Comment: Glad it worked, I was stuck on it for a while too, the documentation is kind of thin and scattered around.